# Making a right aligned triangle with a phrase

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to get the following on Python 3:

```
Please enter a word or phrase: Computer Science
e
ce
nce
ence
ience
cience
Science
Science
r Science
er Science
ter Science
uter Science
puter Science
mputer Science
omputer Science
Computer Science
```

So we had to define this function called `word_processor`that takes no parameters. So far I have this down for it:

```
def main():
    word_processor()

def word_processor():
    value = input("Please enter a word or phrase: ")
    word = len(value)
    for i in range(-1, word + 1):
        print(' ' * (word - i) * i)

main()
```

Whenever I run this code, it tells me to put the phrase and from there, it does nothing. I have no idea what I am doing and I need some help. If someone could help with this, I would greatly appreciate it so much!

Comment: I think you need to use `raw_input()`, not `input()`.

Comment: @CarlGroner, `raw_input()` doesn't exist in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

It does something, it even prints something; but that what it prints is just whitespace:

```
print(' ' * (word - i) * i)
```

This just prints `(word - i) * i` times a space character, so of course you don’t see anything.

In order to produce the output you desire, you would need to do something like this:

```
for i in range(1, len(value) + 1):
    print(value[-i:])
```

Comment: This helped a lot! Thank you so much!